# SyntaxError: (unicode error) 'unicodeescape' codec can't decode bytes in position 2-3: truncated \UXXXXXXXX escape error using Selenium and Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver

I'm confused as to what is causing this error:

**The chrome version is 100.0.4986 which is the latest**
[Google chrome version](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8JMDq.png)

**Python version is 3.9.1:**
[Python version](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lmWb2.png)

**Chrome web driver version is 100.0:**
[Chrome webdriver version](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YYVJB.png)

**Path and location of web driver(ADDED.exe):**

[Path and location of web driver](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9ebtZ.png)

**Modified code below based on feedback:**

```
   from selenium import webdriver

driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=r'C:\Users\sanas\OneDrive\CSIT 110 Python\chromedriver.exe')

driver.get("https://www.google.com")
```

**Error:**

[CMD](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dnceF.png)

Answer (score 0):

Backslash `\` is an escape character, so you have to use `\\`
Change your code to:

```
driver = webdriver.Chrome('C:\\Users\\sanas\\OneDrive\\CSIT 110 Python\\chromedriver')
```

Comment: @Akzy When I downloaded webdriver It did not show .exe Please see this image https://i.stack.imgur.com/Dq6JZ.png

Comment: @Akzy does that mean we rename driver to chromedriver.exe

Answer (score 0):

***Solution:***

Use the `\\` in window and provide the complete path, you forget to add `.exe`

```
driver = webdriver.Chrome('C:\\Users\\sanas\\OneDrive\\CSIT 110 Python\\chromedriver.exe')
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use one of following :

```
driver = webdriver.Chrome('C:\\Users\\sanas\\OneDrive\\CSIT\\Python\\chromedriver.exe'
```

Or

```
driver = webdriver.Chrome('C:/Users/sanas/OneDrive/CSIT/Python/chromedriver.exe'
```

Answer (score 0):

This error message...

```
SyntaxError: (unicode error) 'unicodeescape' codec can't decode bytes in position 2-3: truncated \UXXXXXXXX escape
```

...implies that there was ***unicode escape error*** within the path of the chromedriver.

---

### Solution

You need to modify a couple of things here as follows:

- First and foremost, as you are on [windows](/questions/tagged/windows) system you need to append the extension of the binary executable as well i.e. *`.exe`*
- As you are using single backslashes i.e. `\` you need to add the raw prefix *`r`*
- Ideally you should add the *key* *`executable_path`* as well.

Your effective code block will be:

```
from selenium import webdriver

driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=r'C:\Users\sanas\OneDrive\CSIT 110 Python\chromedriver.exe')
driver.get("https://www.google.com")
```

Comment: Thank you for your feedback, based on it I have made a couple of changes but for some reason I still see an error Please see the above changes in the question thanks a lot

Comment: `Chromedriver not in path` is a different error all together. Feel free to raise a new question as per your new requirements.

Comment: Sure apart from"Chromedriver not in path" do you think everything else seems in order?

Comment: Ofcoarse yes, I guess I have covered all the points where you needed adjustments.

Answer (score 0):

I also got the same error.

```
SyntaxError: (unicode error) 'unicodeescape' codec can't decode bytes in position 2-3: truncated \UXXXXXXXX escape
```

'
I have resolved by adding  `\\`  instead of `\` . Sometime `\` would treated as is an escape character here.

```
   from selenium import webdriver
driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=r'C:\\Users\\sanas\\OneDrive\\CSIT 110 Python\\chromedriver.exe')
  driver.get("https://www.google.com")
```